# trigonometry-use the fact that sin61=sin(60+1) to give an approximate value of sin61 in terms of pi

Tags: trigonometry

Use the fact that $\sin(61^{\circ}) =\sin(60^{\circ}+1^{\circ})$ to give an approximate value of $\sin(61^{\circ})$ degrees in terms of $\pi$

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you seen other problems like this before?  Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use compound angle formulae to get an expression for $\sin (61^\circ)$ in terms of $\sin (60^\circ)$, $\cos (60^\circ)$, $\sin (1^\circ)$ and $\cos (1^\circ)$.
2. You should know exact values for $\sin (60^\circ)$ and $\cos (60^\circ)$.
3. You can use small angle approximations to give $\sin (1^\circ)$ and $\cos (1^\circ)$ in terms of $\pi$ by substituting $1^\circ = \frac \pi {180}$.

That's about it.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that $sin(x) \approx x$ for values of $x \leq 45^{\circ}$, so figuring out what $sin(1)$ is approximately equal to shouldn't be hard. Hence, in this case I would go ahead and refer you to the sine sum formula and use this fact to approximate. You also know what $sin(60)$ is from the unit circle. Since your teacher wants an approximation you should give a few decimal places in your answer. Use the conversion for $\pi$ given above.